# three.js : How to change a parameter of a CylinderGeometry after its instantiation

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have a cylinder with this geometry:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 5, 9, nbVertices, 0, true, Math.PI, 2*Math.PI );
```

The last parameter is the thetaLength property. At some point, I want to change its value later on my website. But when I update it like this:

```
cylinder.geometry.parameters.thetaLength = newValue;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Nothing seems to change. Plus I can read this on the THREE.JS documentation:

> Any modification after instantiation does not change the geometry.

Does anyone knows if there's a way to force this modification? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not just recreate it?

Comment: @DacreDenny, thanks for your answer, I want to animate it, so I'm using the requestAnimationFrame function. I was telling myself it would kind of heavy to delete my cylinder from my scene and recreate it at every frame, don't you think ?

Comment: It depends, if you're only recreating a few of these per frame then you might find this is workable?

Comment: Not such a big deal for your system to re-build geometry on every frame: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=mem#webgl_test_memory Of course, if there are not so many objects in a scene.

Comment: This is perfect, I want to validate one comment to close this topic, how can I do that ? thanks again